# Why is Chrome typing backwards after text selection?

Tags: google-chrome, touchpad

In Chrome, something after I select text in a textbox and start typing to replace it, whatever I type gets typed backwards from right to left. So "abcd" appears in "cdba". This only happens for like a second, then it goes back to left to right like I normally type.

It also only happens when I use my mouse or trackpad to drag select text, if I use a keyboard shortcut like cmd + a to select all, or double/triple click my mouse, it doesn't happen. I'm also getting different results if I select from right to left compared to left to right. I think the mouse cursor is getting stuck after I select something, but I don't know how to fix it.

I tried opening an incognito window to see if it was an extension, but it happens there too. I thought this might be an OSX issue, but it looks like it only happens in Chrome.

This has actually been happening for years.

Comment: Latest version of chrome? Have you tried a chrome factory reset? https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en-GB

Comment: I'd start by disabling all extensions rather than trusting incognito to do it.

Comment: I do use the latest stable chrome